# Simulate checkbox hover effect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I simulate the effect that happens to a checkbox when you hover over it using jQuery? When you do this in Chrome and Firefox, the checkbox input is highlighted blue.

To give a bit more context, I have a grid like so:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>this is a checkbox</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table
```

I want to make it that the checkbox is highlighted the default blue colour when a user hovers over the `<tr>`

I realise I could put a label around `this is a checkbox` and reference the checkbox with the `for` attribute, however I would rather trigger this effect on hover over the `<tr>`.

I'm a bit suspicious about using CSS to style the checkbox input itself as it seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Whhy do you want to simulate it if it already does it? Checkboxes are SO dependent, it'll look different in mac linux etc...

Comment: @Fresheyeball I've given some more detail in the question.

Comment: You can use icon fonts and spans to replace the checkbox like I do in my plugin here http://code.google.com/p/idealforms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/edit after your edit: Some browsers (like Opera) seem to allow you to do things like `padding-right:100px` so that hovering the mouse near the checkbox would highlight the checkbox as well. You can try waste some time with that, but I'd highly recommend you do it with libraries.

That blueish hover sort of thing is from the operating system. Only imaginable way would've been to focus it but obviously it doesn't work.

You can do what we've all been doing for the past decade, turn checkboxes into hidden inputs and use images. Plenty of libraries out there.

[Here's one](https://github.com/emblematiq/Niceforms).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your best bet for looks consistency is to replace the checkbox with your own crafted checkbox. I extracted and edited this from a plugin I made a while ago.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/jTteE/

**html:**

```
<label><input type="checkbox">Hey</label>
```

**css:**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -9999px;
}
.check {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: .5em;
    width: 1.1em;
    height: 1.1em;
    background: #ddd;
}
.check:hover {
    background: pink;
}
.check.checked {
    background: red;
}
.check.checked:after {
    content: "\2713";
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 16px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    color: white;
}
```

**js:**

```
// Check
$('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).before('<span class="check"></span>');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prev('span').addClass('checked');
    }
}).change(function() {
    $(this).prev('span').toggleClass('checked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Mr. ajbeaven, meet the `<label>` tag! **;-)**

**ANSWER:** http://jsfiddle.net/wh5N9/76/
No javascript, just **HTML**...

*Any mouse action done to a **label** will reflect on its **checkbox** (this includes hovering, and clicking).*

> The `<label>` tag defines a label for an  element.
>
> The `<label>` element does not render as anything special for the
>   user. **However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users**,
>   because if the user clicks on the text within the `<label>` element,
>   it toggles the control.
>
> The for attribute of the `<label>` tag should be equal to the id
>   attribute of the related element to bind them together.

You would just need to match the **checkbox id** inside the **label's "for"** attribute, as seen below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="YAHOO"><label for="YAHOO">whatever whatever</label>
```

You can have as many labels for a checkbox, and style them with a fixed width and height so it can be as high or as wide as you want it to be, and fit right inside that **tr** of yours.

*I was able to target checkbox clicking on a `tr` click using jQuery, but not simulate its hovering effect. Thus, I had to fall back on the `<label>`.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I am aware that you can do with with labels but my question was specifically related to creating the same effect with a different element. In this instance it's a `<tr>` because I want it so the checkbox's hover state is applied if the mouse is over any part of the row. There are more `<td>` elements than I have shown with the example code in OP.